# Creating a Training Job using sagemaker estimator gives me "error: unrecognized arguments: train"

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, amazon-sagemaker

I am using a docker image which have all required files and then push it to aws ecr where i can use that image to pass to estimator. I have added the train.py file as entrypoint in dockerfile.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "-m","train"]
```

This works as required in local with `docker run -it image` **but when running training job i get the error.**

```
Training - Training image download completed. Training in progress...usage: train.py [-h] [--epochs EPOCHS] [--learning_rate LEARNING_RATE]
                [--max_sequence_length MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH]
                [--train_batch_size TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE]
                [--valid_batch_size VALID_BATCH_SIZE]
train.py: error: unrecognized arguments: train
```

The training job using sagemaker estimator:

```
estimator = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(image, # docker image
                                          role,
                                          train_instance_count=1, 
                                          train_instance_type='ml.p2.xlarge', 
                                          output_path=output_path, 
                                          hyperparameters=hyperparameters,
                                          sagemaker_session=session
                                         )
```

Train.py main fun():

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--epochs', type=int, default=2)
    parser.add_argument('--learning_rate', type=float, default=2e-5)
    parser.add_argument('--max_sequence_length', type=int, default=512)
    parser.add_argument('--train_batch_size', type=int, default=12)
    parser.add_argument('--valid_batch_size', type=int, default=8)
    # SageMaker environment variables.
    #parser.add_argument('--hosts', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_HOSTS'])
    #parser.add_argument('--current_host', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_CURRENT_HOST'])
    # Parse command-line args and run main.
    args = parser.parse_args()
    # Get SageMaker host information from runtime environment variables
    #sm_hosts = json.loads(args.hosts)
    #sm_current_host = args.current_host
    train(args)
```

From [sagemaker doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-training-algo-dockerfile.html) i was able to find that image in training job runs as `docker run image train` and when i tried to the same in local i got the same error.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `train.py` is at root level or working directory of your docker,

Following code should solve the issue for you:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "train.py"]
```

More info:
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own/scikit_bring_your_own.ipynb

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to define the `ENTRYPOINT` at all. What I do is simply have a `train` (with no file extension) file with my training code. Be sure to make it executable and put it in `/opt/ml/code`. See the complete code [here](https://github.com/roccopietrini/TFSagemakerDetection).

Answer (score 0):

Follow development guide, use ENV SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM train.py

[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/adapt-training-container.html#:~:text=Step%202%3A%20Create%20and%20upload%20the%20Dockerfile%20and%20Python%20training%20scripts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/adapt-training-container.html#:%7E:text=Step%202%3A%20Create%20and%20upload%20the%20Dockerfile%20and%20Python%20training%20scripts)

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.